# Highlight word, depending on its prior use in the file

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I try to color a word depending on its prior use. For example I have the following text file

> **a** : Type1
>
> b : Type2
>
> And now I will take about **a** and b

So Ideally I would like to define `Type1` within the `syntax` file so that `a` gets highlighted whenever used afterwards in the text. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish this you'll need to write an expression that matches your `var: TypeN` situation.

```
let type1Match = '\(.*\): Type1'
```

You can find all matches and store them in a list by using `vimgrep` and `getqflist()`.

```
function FindMatches(regex)
  try
    silent execute "vimgrep /" . a:regex . "/j %"
  catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E480/
    return []
  endtry
  return split(join(map(copy(getqflist()), 'matchlist(v:val.text, a:regex)[1]')))
endfunction
```

This function returns a list containing all match cases or and empty list if none are found. To find all cases of `var: Type1` use

```
:echo FindMatches(type1Match)
```

The last step is to execute `syntax match` on this list.

```
execute "syntax match type1Keyword \"\\<\\(" . join(FindMatches(type1Match), '\|') . "\\)\\>\""
```

You can add this into your syntax file and when the file is saved and loaded it will execute.

One thing to note. This will highlight all cases of the match value. In your example the  `a` in `a: Type1` and in `And now I will talk about a and b` will both be highlighted. You can make your syntax highlighter smarter by highlighting the specific `a: Type1` situation differently but requires a match case of `.*:\s*Type[0-9]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps me a lot to quickly scan trough my files.